# What should I do for GradleException Error in flutter program?

Tags: flutter, gradle

I have a problem in flutter program in GradleException. Now I'm using Gradle 8.0 version and I have tried so many versions of gradle like 7.3.0 and 7.5 and I tried FileNotFoundException & RuntimeException and also I've changed the module SDK to latest one and did invalidate cache and restart. Still I have a same error. So I need a help here.

Now I'm creating a app with flutter and I'm a new user for this. Could you guys please help me on this?

Comment: Can you post the error code of what does the GradleException says

Comment: It shows "Cannot resolve symbol 'GradleException'"

Comment: check anywhere in your code where you use GradleException (in your app/build.gradle) perhaps your problem is that it cannot find your flutter SDK

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

create a new flutter project, check there gradle versions, copy them paste into current one

Comment: I did that too, it has same error on it